# Spark-Kafka Stream- Duplicate Kafka messages

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

0I am using Spark DStreams to consume data from a Kafka topic, which has 5 partitions. Below is code for the same:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe

Object SparkKafkaListener extends Serializable {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val spark = SparkSession.Builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
     val kafkaConfig = Map[String, Object](<Kafka Configurations>)
     val sc = spark.sparkContext
     val topic = Array("topic")
     
     // Creating Streaming Context
     @transient
     val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(300))
     
     // Building Spark-Kafka DStreams object
     val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
        ssc,
        PreferConsistent,
        Subscribe[String, String](topic, kafkaConfig)
     )
     
     // Iterating over stream of RDDs and performing some operation
     // Committing offsets in the end after storing Kafka message and header
     stream.foreachRDD((rdd, batchTime) => {
        val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
        rdd.map(value => (value.value())).saveAsTextFile("path")

        rdd.map(message => message.headers()).map(y => 
        {y.iterator}).map(x => x.next()).map(y => 
          y.value().map(_.toChar).mkString)
        .saveAsTextFile("path")

        val commits = new offsetCommit(logger, util, props,batchID,x12Type)
        stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges, commits)
      }
     )
    )
  
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()


   }
}
```

After saving messages from Kafka Topic, I'm trying to commit the offsets in range via `commitAsync` call. The issue here is that this call is executed in consecutive run but not the current. For instance, offsets of batch1 stream are getting committed only after the batch2 execution completes, instead it should be happening just after the batch1 completes. This issue is leading to data duplicity and sometimes data loss.

Not sure if I'm missing some property which would immediately commit offsets of the respective batch of stream without any lag. Would really appreciate any help towards this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use Structured Streaming?

Comment: Yes, we are consuming header field from the topic using Spark 2.4.4, which doesn't exist as in its Structured Streaming API, but in DStreams.

Comment: The given example doesn't use headers, but sure... In any case, when you say the call is executed in the consecutive run, what does this really mean? The commit is async, so there is no guarantee when it'll actually complete. If you change it to `commitSync`, then what do you see?

Comment: I am using it in the actual code, didn't have it here initially but included now. 

The stream is configured to run every 5 minutes. So in the first run, once rdds are processed, the `commitAsync` is called; however it actually completes in the second batch run. I verified that through logs. But as you said it's an `Async` operation, not sure when it would complete. On `commitSync`,  I'm unable to see any such method against the stream.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of just kafka api, not Spark https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27456 I guess the alternative is to use Kafka Connect instead, assuming you're writing data to S3 or HDFS. Both of those connectors support exactly once, as well

Comment: I see, so its a known issue being worked upon. Thanks fo sharing the JIRA link, that's exactly what I'm facing. I have to explore Kafka Connect and check how exactly is it going to achieve what I'm looking for. Thanks @OneCricketeer